# How to override email input validator message?

Tags: javascript, validation, email, popup, alert

I have an email input like this, basically there will be 3 original validators.

- If I don't type anything, it will show `Please fill in this field`.
- If I type something without @ , e.g `a` : , it shows `Please include an @ in the email address...`
- If I type something with @ but not finish, e.g `a@` . it shows `Please enter a part following @...`

Now I need to override the existing popup with my own alert, lets say `"alert1", "alert2" , "alert3"`. But I'm having difficulty writing code to differentiate between these three. Any help please.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>validity.typeMismatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <label>Email Address:<br><input name="txtemail" id="txtemail" required="required" type="email"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Register..">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Leave the browser's own popups for field validation since it does everything it already needs.  You're not only trying to reinvent the wheel, but you're also trying to make the user's browser do something unexpected.  This is a bad idea.  If you do insist on doing it then remove the `required` attribute, change `type` to `type="text"` and write your own validation handler.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yes i think i should go with your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {

    const dom = document.getElementById('txtemail')

    if (!$('#txtemail').val()) {
        dom.setCustomValidity('alert1')
    } else if ($('#txtemail').val().indexOf('@') === -1) {
        dom.setCustomValidity('alert2')
    } else if ($('#txtemail').val().indexOf('@') === $('#txtemail').val().length - 1) {
        dom.setCustomValidity('alert3')
    }
})
```